Azure LogicApp Connection to DevOps bring the failure The account name you entered is invalid
I have a Logic app that establishes a connection to DevOps via the standard connector.
Here I perform various activities (GetQuery, Update Item...)
Since 10 June it no longer runs reliably and sometimes in a loop it gives the following error for an item:
Used connector -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/

Code:
{
  "type": "ApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
    "host": {
      "connection": {
        "referenceName": "visualstudioteamservices"
      }
    },
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/_apis/wit/workitems/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_DevOps_Item')?['System.Id'])}",
    "queries": {
      "account": "@variables('account')",
      "project": "@variables('DevOpsProject')",
      "typeName": "@{items('For_each_DevOps_Item')['System.WorkItemType']}"
    }
  }
}

It also happen when i not use a variable as account, that was the initial setup for over one year.

Code:
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The account name you entered is invalid. Enter 'fabrikam' if your Azure DevOps URL is 'fabrikam.visualstudio.com'.\r\nclientRequestId: XXXXXXXXXX",
  "error": {
    "message": "The account name you entered is invalid. Enter 'fabrikam' if your Azure DevOps URL is 'fabrikam.visualstudio.com'."
  },
  "source": "vsts-we.azconn-we-002.p.azurewebsites.net"
}

Does anyone know the problem?
I have already tested everything:

Connection API re-verified
Checked authorisations
Nobody has changed anything ...


What value you have defined for {account}?

Hi @Daniel, Has the name of your Azure DevOps organization changed? From the error message, it was pointing to the Azure DevOps organization name, which should be input as the value of {account} in your workflow.

it was not changed, and the error only occurs sporadically and occurs 2-3 times in a loop of 100 passes

So you mean this is a sporadic error which can be succeeded without any change? What if you hardcoded the values, will the issue persist?

yes it is the same. put i via variable or select it via drop down. and it doesn't just happen with one logicapp, but with all those that have a connector to devops.

Could the issue happen every time you ran the workflow? Did all the apps get work item details from the same organization via the connector by the single same user account of yours?

yes every time since10 of june. All are running with my account!

How would the workflow in my answer below work for you? If not, may I know if the loop oF GET requests failed with any specific work items or just random work items?

I have been able to reproduce your problem, starting roughly a week ago. I tried changing API versions and service connection details. It just randomly fails in the workflow in different places (get, update etc.)
I believe that this is a bug, and I have reported a problem using your text.

Based on your description, I succeeded in retrieving the details of each work item from the 200 results of a query. Here is the sample workflow for your reference.


For each
{
  "type": "Foreach",
  "foreach": "@body('Get_query_results')?['value']",
  "actions": {
    "Get_work_item_details": {
      "type": "ApiConnection",
      "inputs": {
        "host": {
          "connection": {
            "referenceName": "visualstudioteamservices"
          }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/_apis/wit/workitems/@{encodeURIComponent(item()?['System.Id'])}",
        "queries": {
          "account": "@variables('account')",
          "project": "@variables('DevOpsProject')",
          "typeName": "@item()?['System.WorkItemType']"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Get_query_results": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}


This is exactly the same structure as I have. The Logic apps have now been running for months without any errors.
In one call it works and in the same loop in the next call with the same method but on a different item (not always the same one) the error occurs

I also suspect your account might have been causing usage spikes and hit the rate limits, considering you have several apps sending requests against your single account. Have you tested with other user's account to run the same workflow?

that was my first thought too. I then re-authenticated the API connection. Unfortunately without success.
The error only occurs sporadically and occurs 2-3 times in a loop of 100 passes

Given that it stopped working on a specific day and that nobody changed anything.
It could be that the account or the password of the account has expired.

After a week, all my LogicApps are working again without errors. It really looks like something in the Azure backend didn't work. Thank you very much for your quick commitment and help.

Thanks for taking time to share the update. Cheers.
